# Python name of iterable that can be iterated many times

Tags: python

I'm trying to improve my documentation.  I want to say that this function accepts something that is a collections.Iterable, but the code will iterate over the iterable many times.  A "list" is too specific, and an "iterable" doesn't work because some iterables can only be iterated once.

Is there a name for a thing?  "Re-iterable"?  Multiple-iterable?

Comment: Not answering your question, but I would suggest you might use itertools.tee in your code - so that it could accept any iterable at all.

Comment: @jsbueno:  This would introduce a redundant copy when passing in a sequence, though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Actually, "tee" does just "the right thing" - it would only have "multiple copies" of sequence values that where used once, but not yet all times. The problem need to be one very resource-critical for this caching to be an issue at all. AND if it was, it would be a matter of an `if` for not using `tee` if a sequence was passed in.

Comment: @jsbueno: Why doesn't tee automatically do the right thing when a sequence is passed to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of anything appropriate.  Reiterable sounds like a nice term, why not define it clearly in your documentation then use it?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want the term ["sequence"](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-sequence).  A sequence in Python is something that has a length and supports item access by index.

Comment: That might be too specific also though - for example a linked list doesn't support access by index, but is still reiterable.

Comment: @SideshowBob: I don't think this is too restrictive in practice.  The only linked-list implementation that comes with Python is the chunked linked list `deque`, which is a sequence as well.  Of course accessing by index is O(n) for a `deque`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: A ValuesView is "reiterable", but doesn't support access by index in general.